# Wordpress Multisite childsite image upload path incorrect

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, file-upload, multisite

after banging my head against this for many hours, i thought i would try to explain things on here to try and find anyone that might of encountered the same behavior

i am running multisite with one parent site, and one child site, the parent site is working fine, but...

after updating my wordpress multisite to 4.7.3 my child site has "lost" all of its images, on closer inspection the images havnt been lost, they are being uploaded to a different part of the server, however, the image upload path seems to be using the "old" path, for example, if i upload image1.jpg it gets uploaded to:

http://my-url.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/7/files/2017/04/image1.jpg

however, on the media page(and front end of the site), the image is displaying as a broken image, the image path is:

http://my-url.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/files/2017/04/image1.jpg

i have tried changing the upload path in the network admin settings for the site here:

/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=7

i have changed the upload path to /wp-content/uploads/sites/7 to no avail

my multisite root .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and the editable part of my wp-config.php looks like this:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
 /** no auto update */
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '**hidden-for-privacy**.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); // 
//define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

i am running no plugins and using the twentyseventeen theme (to avoid any conflicts associated with that!)

so has anyone else encountered this? if so how did you fix it? im literally pulling my hair out looking for a needle in a haystack, any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Tommy

Comment: do you use, $siteId = get_current_blog_id(); switch_to_blog( $siteId ); before call images in to your function?

Comment: sorry, im not sure what you mean? what function are you asking about?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog           get current blog id use to get current blog id of page and use to fetch data of particular site table.

Comment: im not using any custom function, i have a completely empty website (child site in multisite) when i upload an image, its being uploaded to the wrong place, all using the standard wordpress image upload functionality

Comment: Have you gone through above links?

Comment: yes ive gone through those links, but im not using either of those functions, all im trying to do is upload an image to my media library, the image is not displaying, this is because its being uploaded to a different directory on my server, thus breaking the image display

Comment: If your displaying images by get URL from database then you have to use above function to get exact path of particular blog, if your not getting path from database then you have to check if images exist in directory folder or not..

Comment: im not trying to display the image, im trying to get to the bottom of why the image is being uploaded here:

/wp-content/blogs.dir/7/files/2017/04/image1.jpg

but when being displayed by the media library, the images url is this:

/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/files/2017/04/image1.jpg

therefore displaying a broken image link, the image is on the server but for some reason wordpress is looking for it in the wrong place